# web service thru old perl version

Tags: perl, client, perl-module

when I am using upgrade version of perl (ofcourse, also upgrade version of soap::lite)
so I successfully connect to my server with all needed methods.
when I moved using older perl version (ofcourse, also older version of soap::lite), so envelope created differently, and I did not success invoke server methods which got params 
well.
Is there need change something in code or only in modules?
If change can be done thru code, so which thing I need to change. for now my code look like:

```
my $ws_url = '$url';
my $ws_uri = '$uri';
my $ws_xmlns = '$xmlns';            

eval
{
                  my $soap = SOAP::Lite
                  -> uri( $ws_uri)
                  -> on_action(sub{sprintf '%s', @_})
                  -> proxy($ws_url,timeout => 15);

                 my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name(Add => "$paramAdd"));
                 $response = $soap->EndUnit(@params);

                  if($response->fault)
                  {
                      # die raises an exception
                      print "=======fault happened=====\n";
                      die $response->faultstring;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      print $response->result;
                      print "\n";
                  }
                        };
                        if ($@)
                        {
                          print "$@\n";
                          print "Failed \n";
                        };
```

Thanks a lot ahead for your help!
Noa :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the changes between the versions of SOAP::Lite you are using : [Changes](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MKUTTER/SOAP-Lite-0.712/Changes)

Also, you shold list what versions of Perl and SOAP::Lite you are talking about ..